# Separating a string pair from a list

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and while practicing random puzzles with python, I came across this question.

Given a list that is in a format like this: `data=['x y', 'x y']`,
For example `data= ['201.3 49.6', '214.5 51.89', '201.6 43.2']`

How can one use `data` and turn it into two separate lists of `x` and `y`? In this case, the answer should look like `x=[201.3, 214.5, 201.6]` and `y=[49.6, 51.89, 43.2]`

My original was approach was noticing that I had to somehow unpair x and y string pair from `data`, so I thought about using `unzip` command in python, however, I don't know how to use it or even if its the right approach for this question.

Comment: [`x, y = list(zip(*(x.split(' ') for x in data)))`](https://akuiper.com/console/5afxkB9wEirc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = ['201.3 49.6', '214.5 51.89', '201.6 43.2']

s_pairs = [ps.split() for ps in data]
x = [float(s[0]) for s in s_pairs]
y = [float(s[1]) for s in s_pairs]
print(x)  # [201.3, 214.5, 201.6]
print(y)  # [49.6, 51.89, 43.2]
```